# Not able to place two div's next to each other, tried everything

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the text to the right of the image, and the image and the text should be positioned a little to the right of the page, but it is just not working for me.

```
<div id="container">

<div class="desc">
    <div>
        <img class="imgD" src="C:\Users\Hadia\Dropbox\college\unit 14 Webdesign\images\red-lipstic.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class=".introHeader">
        <h4> Red Lipstic | MAC </h4>
        <p class="price">&#163;20.00</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6p1k0cqa/

Comment: Like this? ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6p1k0cqa/2/).

Comment: Consider looking up `float`

Comment: A note: You should read the description about the tags you use. The tag `jsfiddle` is `For questions about using jsFiddle` and not to show that you have a jsfiddle included.

Comment: @t.niese sorry my mistake still new to this. thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new  to contain the text (the  and the two

s), and then call

```
width: 33%
float: left;
```

on the image div and

```
width: 60%
float: right;
```

on the text div, adjusting the widths however you like. Also, on any content you add below, make sure to

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: please edit this fiddle click save and give me the link http://jsfiddle.net/6p1k0cqa/